# How to merge MP3 files?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

What's the best way to merge X MP3 files? Same length. I don't want to concatenate them, basically just want to merge/overlay them

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't really about linux, its a request for a software recommendation and as such should be posted to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

The operation you want is technically called **mixing**, not "merging".

The command-line tool `sox` can do it. The GUI application `Audacity` can do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **audacity** and merge the MP3s manually or via its scripting.
In order to support MP3 Import/Export, you will need specifically the **audacity-freeworld** package, since it is compiled against FFMpeg.

### Using GUI

1. File -> Import -> Audio -> (select mp3 file)
2. Repeat for each file
3. File -> Export Audio -> Select Mp3 format and save

### Using script

It seems to be possible to use perl scripts to interface with Audacity. For more details of how to enable this read [here](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html):